# Finding 111 plane of Carbon Diamond

Tags: graphics3d, physics, chemistry, lattices, polyhedra

All,

I looked at the example on the Mathematica Website with the Carbon Diamond Lattice.
[Example I am referring to](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DiamondLattice/)

I am wondering is there a way to highlight an individual plane such as the 111 or 110 plane? I like the example I am just not sure of my orientation.

Cheers,
BEn

---

Code:

```
Manipulate[
 tet = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Faces"];
 tetv = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
 sp = {RGBColor[1, 1, 0.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, sizes]};
 bar1 = {RGBColor[0.2, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}}, sizec]};
 bar2 = {RGBColor[0.3, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}},
     sizec]};
 bar3 = {RGBColor[0.4, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}}, 
    sizec]};
 bar4 = {RGBColor[0.5, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[3], 0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}}, sizec]};
 sp4 = Map[Translate[sp, #] &, tetv];
 base = {bar4, bar3, bar2, bar1, sp4, sp, If[tets, tet, {}]};
 dia = Rotate[
   Rotate[Map[Translate[base, #] &, tetv], -Cos[Sqrt[3]/3/2], {0, 1, 
     0}], Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}];

 cub = If[cubs, 
   Scale[PolyhedronData["Cube", "Edges"], 
    Sqrt[2] {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], {}];
 diax = Table[Translate[{dia, cub}, {i Sqrt[2], 0, 0}], {i, n}];
 diay = Table[Translate[{dia, cub, diax}, {0, i Sqrt[2], 0}], {i, n}];
 diaz = Table[
   Translate[{dia, cub, diax, diay}, {0, 0, i Sqrt[2]}], {i, n}];

 Graphics3D[{dia, cub, diax, diay, diaz}, Boxed -> False, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 380],
 {{n, 0, "frequency"}, 0, 2, 1, RadioButton},
 {{sizec, 0.025, "cylinder size"}, 0, 0.5},
 {{sizes, 0.1, "sphere size"}, 0, 0.5},
 {{tets, False, "show tetrahedra"}, {True, False}},
 {{cubs, False, "show cubes"}, {True, False}}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> Manipulate]
```

Comment: Please, can you be more specific ? If possible provide the code you are working on to illustrate by example what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry there is not enough space in the comment to put the code so I will put it as an answer to my own question. However the code is on the link to the page I provided.

 I am not sure what you mean by more specific. I would like to know when I am looking down the 111 lattice plane.

Comment: @user1558881 You can edit the question to add your code. Please also ensure proper markup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A convenient resource for the Miller Indices can be found [here](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/surfaces/scc/scat1_1b.htm).  This ref provides sufficient information for us to draw the (111) and (110) planes.  First, reproduce the graphic from the demonstration.  I just made the necessary changes to make it run outside of a `Manipulate` and did not try to optimize it.

```
tet = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Faces"];
tetv = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
sp = {RGBColor[1, 1, 0.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]};
bar1 = {RGBColor[0.2, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}}, 0.025]};
bar2 = {RGBColor[0.3, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}},
     0.025]};
bar3 = {RGBColor[0.4, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}}, 
    0.025]};
bar4 = {RGBColor[0.5, 1, 1], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[3], 0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}}, 0.025]};
sp4 = Map[Translate[sp, #] &, tetv];
base = {bar4, bar3, bar2, bar1, sp4, sp};
dia = Rotate[
   Rotate[Map[Translate[base, #] &, tetv], -Cos[Sqrt[3]/3/2], {0, 1, 
     0}], Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}];


diax = Table[Translate[{dia}, {i Sqrt[2], 0, 0}], {i, 1}];
diay = Table[Translate[{dia, diax}, {0, i Sqrt[2], 0}], {i, 1}];
diaz = Table[Translate[{dia, diax, diay}, {0, 0, i Sqrt[2]}], {i, 1}];

Graphics3D[{dia, diax, diay, diaz}, Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 380]
```

The (110) plane has the coordinates defined as shown below:

[image]

Which is easily replicated in Mathematica:

```
axis = Arrow /@ {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 
 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}
p110 = {Opacity[0.5], Black, 
  Polygon[{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 2}, {2, 0, 2}}]}
p111 = {Opacity[0.5], Black, Polygon[{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]}
```

I add the axis symbol just for reference.  Combining these graphics with the original gives

```
Graphics3D[{dia, diax, diay, diaz, axis, p110}, Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 380]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And for the (111)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can tweak the values in p111 and p110 to suit your needs for the size of the plane.

Comment: Perfect thanks!